# Content Provider being re-rendering mulitple times in Next.js 13 application

Tags: next.js, next.js13

I have a content provider for a simple shopping cart in my Next.js 13 app directory. The problem that i'm having is that the `addToCart()` function is being called numerous times each time i call the function. This causes issues particularly when i have a item quantity which increments each time `addToCart()` is called, thus giving the wrong quantity value.

```
function addToCart({ id, item_title, item_price, restrict: boolean }) {
   console.log("addToCart funtion hit")
   updateCart((prev) => {
     console.log("updateCart funtion hit")
   })
}
```

The output in inspector reads like this:

```
addToCart funtion hit
updateCart funtion hit
updateCart funtion hit
```

If I add `reactStrictMode: false` to my next.congif.js config file, the function call is reduced to 1 indicating that is has to do when the component being rendered multiple times. I've read that setting `reactStrictMode: false` on next.config.js is bad practice, so was attempting to implement that setting for the only the test-cart.js component, but to no avail.

In the root of the directory i have a layout.tsx file which loads the test-cart.js like this:

```
"use client"

import './globals.css'
import { CountryCodeProvider } from '../context/countrycode';
import { CartContext, useCartState } from '../hooks/test-cart.js';

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {

  const cartState = useCartState();
  cartState.restrict = false;

  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <main>
          <>
            <CountryCodeProvider>
              <CartContext.Provider value={cartState}>
                {children}
              </CartContext.Provider>
            </CountryCodeProvider>
          </>
        </main>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

and for test-cart.js i have the following code:

```
"use client"
import { useState, createContext, useContext } from 'react';

export const CartContext = createContext();

export function useCartState() {
  const [cart, updateCart] = useState(defaultCart);

  function addToCart({ id, item_title, item_price, restrict: boolean }) {
    console.log("addToCart funtion hit")
    updateCart((prev) => {
      console.log("updateCart funtion hit")
    })
  }

  return {
    addToCart,
    restrict: false, 
  }

}

export function useCart() {
  const cart = useContext(CartContext);
  return cart;
}
```

So i've attempted to implement `cartState.restrict = false;` but unfortunately it doesn't work.

Keep in mind that i've stripped out most of the code to keep this example as small as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced same issue before. only i do thing is add use effect.

try this...

insted of

```
updateCart((prev) => {
      console.log("updateCart funtion hit")
    })
  }
```

add useEffect()

```
useEffect(() => {
      console.log("updateCart function hit");
      updateCart((prev) => {
        // your update logic here
        return prev;
      });
    }, []);
```

im not sure about this.but maybe this will help

Answer (score 0):

I marked Y Nawodya's response as correct and it was the right direction. If anyone is intersted here is the final code.

```
function useCartState() {
  const [cart, updateCart] = useState(defaultCart);
  const [item, setItem] = useState(null); // a state variable to store the item data

  function addToCart({ id, item_title, item_price }) {
    console.log("addToCart funtion hit")
    setItem({ id, item_title, item_price }); 
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (item) { // only run the effect if the item is not null
      console.log("updateCart function hit");
      updateCart((prev) => {
        // your update logic here, using the item data
        return prev;
      });
    }
  }, [item]); // run the effect whenever the item changes

  return {
    addToCart
  }
}
```